# dockerized flask app does not import pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i'm developing a flaskapp that has pandas in it!
it work fine when i run it in localhost but when i dockerize it and try to run the container i get this log:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\testapi\app.py", line 4, in 
> import pandas as pd
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
> TTraceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\testapi\app.py", line 4, in 
> import pandas as pd
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

can you guys solve my problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your dockerfile:
`RUN pip install pandas`

You should consider using a `requirements.txt` file for dependencies.
Copy the `requirements.txt` to your container and install the requirements:
`RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`